# pinchable grid zoom in android

Tags: java, android, scroll, gesture, pinch

I am been googleing this and there really is a distinct absence of physical information regarding this task...

I want to make a grid view in android that uses "tiles" that sorts itself and allows gestures.

The gestures I want to implement are:

- pinch zoom
- scroll including flick
- diagonal scroll

I want the tiles to take data easily including a small thumbnail img. If you rotate the display landscape or portrait the tiles need to realign themselves according to the "zoom" of the pinch (basically they should just "rotate" 90 degrees themselves and not move)

I know this is a hug ask but I was hoping that some of this work had been done before and if so under what name? As a minimum I'd really like to get the pinch / zoom / 2D scroll / grid working from an example##

can anyone help?